Azure Logic App Workflow - Invalid SQL Connector Reference
I am using Terraform to create the following Azure Resources..

One Standard Logic Application with a 'System Assigned Identity' (SAI) - this deploys OK.
One outlook365 connector - this deploys OK.
Link via an 'access policy' the outlook365 connector and the 'SAI' - this deploys OK.

Via a Azure devOps Release Pipeline I deploy out one workflow to the Logic App - the workflow appears.

I force start the workflow and nothing comes up under the 'trigger' or 'run' history..

It looks OK however the Logic App reports...
The workflow is reporting the below error...
Workflow 'wrkflw-custom-sql-alert-1a' is unhealthy. Error:'Failed to read the workflows in directory 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\wrkflw-custom-sql-alert-1a'. Message 'The 'id' property '/serviceProviders/sql/connections/sql' under 'connectionReferences.sql.connection' is not valid.''
The workflow JSON shows the connector reference as below - with the line being reported as having an incorrect value of '/serviceProviders/sql/connections/sql' surrounded with stars...
"connectionReferences": {
        "sql": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/serviceProviders/sql"
            },
            "connection": {
                **"id": "/serviceProviders/sql/connections/sql"**
            },
            "connectionName": "sql"
        }
    }

The connectors under the Az Logic App show...
{
    "managedApiConnections": {
        "office365": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/ABC/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/office365"
            },
            "authentication": "@parameters('office365-Authentication')",
            "connection": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/ABC/resourceGroups/DEF/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365"
            },
            "connectionRuntimeUrl": "@parameters('office365-ConnectionRuntimeUrl')"
        }
    },
    "serviceProviderConnections": {
        "sql": {
            "displayName": "Connection to Database ISL_Management",
            "parameterSetName": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
            "parameterValues": {
                "authProvider": {
                    "Type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                },
                "databaseName": "ISL_Management",
                "managedIdentityType": "SystemAssigned",
                "serverName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-sqlsrv01.database.windows.net"
            },
            "serviceProvider": {
                "id": "/serviceProviders/sql"
            }
        }
    }
}

Any thoughts on what I did wrong?

It looks like API connections are not created correctly. Check the API connection's connectivity

Had to delete logic app, working storage account, connectors and re-create. Errors were showing after re-creation. Went to bed and logic app errors were still there however the next morning and without making any changes logic-app errors had gone away and the workflow was running OK....
